# Find index of the latest date in perl

Tags: perl

I have an array of dates of the form 'YYYY-Month' like '2013-Dec', '2014-May' and so on. I need to find the index of the latest date in the array. Is there any inbuilt module to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the dates using [`Time::Piece strptime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html).

And then use [`date comparisons`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Comparisons) to determine which is the latest.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @strings = qw(2013-Dec 2014-May 2014-Jan 2014-Feb 2014-Jan);
my @dates = map {Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y-%b")} @strings;

my $maxid = reduce {$dates[$b] > $dates[$a] ? $b : $a} (0..$#dates);

print "$strings[$maxid]\n"
```

Outputs:

```
2014-May
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any module then use the below piece of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
use strict;
use warnings;
my @dates = ( '2013-Dec', '2014-May', '1992-July', '2014-Jan' );
my @sorted_dates = sort { (split /\-/, $a)[0] <=> (split /\-/, $b)[0] ||
                          (split /\-/, $a)[1] cmp (split /\-/, $b)[1] 
                        } @dates;
print "Latest date is ".$sorted_dates[-1]. " index is $#sorted_dates";
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/pSeRl7)

Comment: your code sorts the months in alphabetical order. It doesn't work if '1992-July' is replaced by '2014-July'